# create tumbnail in keystone.js on fly using aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, keystonejs

I want to create aws s3 image thumbnail on fly in keystone.js hbs tempalte below is my code have no idea how to achieve this

This is the code of .hbs template where I want to generate thumb on fly

```
{{#if image}}<img src="{{image.url}}"  width=100 height=100 class="img-responsive pull-right" /> {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look for a solution for similar task
https://gist.github.com/dboskovic/23858511bf3c1cbebdbd
https://gist.github.com/stephencoe/a7a3581141582b02fc7e